# outerWidth(true) returns different values two times in a row, without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm baffled.

http://jsfiddle.net/pyn8s/

Click the Login button.
Wait for the popup to appear.
Note its position.
Click the Login button again.
Watch it move to the left. (correct position)
Click the Login button again.
Notice that it doesn't move anymore.

I am at such a loss that I'm not really sure how to even describe this odd behavior. I notice with an alert on note.outerWidth(true) that it reports a different width on the first two login clicks, but the object is never invisible, and it's width should be set before outerWidth is ever called on it...

Comment: The width of `.note` *changes* (from what it was with `left: 0`) when `left: -??px` is set. I don't have time to write a full answer right now.

Comment: I changed the element position to relative and it doesnt do that any more http://jsfiddle.net/pyn8s/5/

Comment: Kishore, that seems to work on my end too, but I don't understand how it works. I thought you could only set left and top if the position was set to absolute.

Comment: Yeah that fixes it, but I still don't understand why the width of the element changes. Maybe I'm too drunk. If anybody can explain it, I certainly give my upvote :).

Comment: Setting form#loginform div.note {width: 100%} also solves the problem.

Comment: @crush you don't need to position: absolute the div.note, it also solves the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When jQuery evaluates note.outerWidth() the first time, it gets its parent width (loginForm = **250px**) because note's width is not defined in the css (only max-width is defined).

The browser renders the new note content after .append() but its new width is calculated after .offset() :

See console log : http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/QSsV6/

```
max-width + 2 * (padding + border-width)
```

= 300px + 2 * (5px + 1px) = **312px**

When you click again, the offset will be calculated based on 312px instead of 250px. That's why note will move to another position.

**Solution 1** : removing 'position: absolute' http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/wjeGF/

Explanation :
If you set position: absolute, note is taken out of the flow and doesn't inherit the width of 250px from loginForm anymore. So its width isn't limited to 250px but to max-width of 300px + padding + border = 312px.
If you don't set position: absolute, note's width will be inherited and equal to 250px (all the time).

**Solution 2** : set default width http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/Ex3Bp/

Comment: I actually put that stuff inside of the function because its all dynamic in my actual project, and i didnt need to put that functionality in this example in order to show the problem. I'm curious as to what actually fixed the error. Was it simply removing the top: 0 and left: 0 initialization in CSS?

Comment: Again, I'd also be curious to know WHY.

Comment: It is rendered as soon as append() happens, since note was not `display:none` initially. Which is before the outerWidth(true) call takes place. Your explanation about this doesn't make sense; however, solution 1 and 2 are plausible.

Comment: @crush you are right. The browser renders the new note content after .append() but its new width is calculated after .offset() : See console log : http://jsfiddle.net/HighKickX/QSsV6/

Comment: Had the same problem when the content of the element I was calling .outerWidth() on was an image. Right when document.ready() is called, the image might not be ready. After the image loads, the second call to .outerWidth() will return the correct value. Setting a width on the container element solved the issue for me, thanks!